# Proof of Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality in the Almost Sure blog

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am currently reading the famous [almost sure](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/) blog by George Lowther about stochastic calculus. I am currently reading the section about the [Burkholder-Davis-Gundi-Inequality](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality/) (BDG inequality). At the end of the blog entry under the title "Continuous-time Local Martingales" he proves the BDG inequality for $p \geq 1$. He uses an approximating sequence

$$[X]^{(n)}_t = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(X_{t^n_k \land t}-X_{t^n_{k-1} \land t})^2 \rightarrow [X]_t$$

which converges in u.c.p. (i.e. uniformly over compact sets in probability) to the quadratic variation of the local-martingale $X$ and by passing to a subsequence we can assume convergence uniformly over compacts P-a.s.. **The parts of the proof I do not understand**, are where he defines

$$M_t := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[X]_t^{(n)}$$

and claims that $(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is RCLL (right continuous admitting left limits) and that its jumps are bounded in the following way
$$\Delta M_t \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Delta [X]_t^{(n)}$$

Has anyone read his blog and knows why we can conclude RCLL and such a bound for the jumps?

Thanks a lot in advance!